Projective modules over locally finite categories
Is the following conjecture true or not?
Conjecture：
Let $R$ be a locally finite-dimensional category, $M$
a projective left $R$-module of the form
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ind-decomp}
M = \oplus_{i \in I} R_{x_i}
\end{equation}
for some small set $I$ and $(x_i)_{i \in I} \in R_0^I$.
Then every direct summand $P$ of $M$ has an indecomposable decomposition.

How about the structure of projective modules over locally-finite category?

What is the question?

Does every direct summand  of  have an indecomposable decomposition?
